# Maven configuration in intellij idea 14

Tags: java, tomcat, intellij-idea, maven-3, intellij-14

can anyone give me the right scenario to make a  maven web project and deploy a war using it in intellij idea with maven 3.2 and tomcat 7/8 and java 8.i'm having trouble with configuring and the folder structure about it and deployment of the web mainly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from memory if you ask IntelliJ to create a new project you should be able to select maven project from the options and then use the maven web app arche type to have it create a skeleton web project for you.

This is from IntelliJ 15 CE but I doubt its that much different in 14.  Notice the checking of the create from archetype box
[image]

Comment: Gavin can you explain further?

Comment: @GayanPrasanna See attached Screen shot.  I don't remember if it will build you a basic POM, but you will need to include a compile plugin and a jar/war plugin, do a search on this site (or google) for plenty of relevant example.  Keep to the Maven file structure and you will reduce the number of issues you have with maven plugins.

Comment: Its been that long since I have used tomcat, but from memory the most basic way to deploy a WAR is to drop it into tomcats applications directory and it should, all being well auto deploy form there.  IntelliJ may have a feature to deploy to a container, but I have never need to use it so don't know.

Comment: thanks for your support Gavin.I have built the web application but it is not running when running from the IDE.it only opens up the chrome as localhost:8080 and it is not showing anything plus if you can please tell me the way to make the war in this IDE

Comment: Have you deployed the application?  As to using the IDE to make the WAR; there should be a maven tag, usually on the right of the IDE, open this it should list your projects, if you open your project, there is a  lifecycle folder under that is a list, these are the phases/goals of a maven project, to build you need to select compile, to create a jar/war package, then press the run icon.  By selecting package it will run all the goals above it.  I usual select clean and install, but clean package should be enough to build your war, assuming you have configured the appropriate plugins.

Comment: The Maven book by Sonotype is very good, if you are going to be using maven for your projects you really should give it a read.

Comment: Yeah I need to get some knowledge on maven obviously.thanks i'll read it.i have configured my project now but still unable to run.for now i'm using cmd and apply mvn clean install and deploy it to the server and running.

Comment: Without actually seeing your project/setup or error message there isn't really much more I can do to help.  The book will help you understand Maven, as will the maven site at apache.org.  I think from here its just a case of reading around your problem.  Good luck.

Comment: additionally to the right are some question others have asked around this same area, perhaps they will help.